# Why is the big O of pop() different from pop(0) in python

Tags: python, algorithm, list, big-o

Shouldn't they both be `O(1)`, as popping an element from any location in a Python list involves destroying that list and creating one at a new memory location?

Comment: @thefourtheye *in a python list*

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Python's `list` implementation uses a dynamically resized C `array` under the hood, removing elements *usually* requires you to move elements following after up to prevent gaps.

`list.pop()` with no arguments removes the *last* element. Accessing that element can be done in constant time. There are no elements following so nothing needs to be shifted.

`list.pop(0)` removes the *first* element. *All* remaining elements have to be shifted up one step, so that takes O(n) linear time.

Comment: why isnt pop(0) O(1)? Can we not just shift the memory pointer of the 0th element of the list up by 1? Like, after pop(0) I just say that my new list starts from its 1st element

Comment: @figs_and_nuts because a Python list is not just that C array, it is a *dynamic resized* array. Removing from the front would wreak havoc with the dynamic resizing. Shifting everything down means that when the list size drops below a threshold reallocating the chunk freed at the end a lot simpler. Not to mention what handling a mix of pop(0) and append operations would do.

Answer (score 11):

To add to Martijn's answer, if you want a datastructure that has constant time pops at both ends, look at [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque).